# Does this write to stdout or stdin?

Tags: linux

If I type the following command in Linux:

```
cat textfile
```

The contents of textfile is displayed. What is cat actually writing to? Is it writing to stdout or stdin?

Comment: You *can't* write *to* stdin. You can only read from it.

Comment: But you can write to _another program's_ stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's writing to `stdout`.

You can check this by trying the following:

```
cat textfile > stdout.log 2> stderr.log
```

You should find that all the output goes to `stdout.log`, not `stderr.log`.